# Error during post API call : type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a post API call in Flutter with http package to check log in of a user.
This is the code of PressedLogin Function

```
if (email != "" && passcode.length >= 4) {
      await myRepo.loginApi(json.encode(dataToSend)).then((value) {
        if (context.mounted) {
          Utils.showSnackbarFunction(context, SnackBarType.success, "Logged in");
        }
        changeLoginStatus();
        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutesName.home);
        }
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        print("Here in error section $error");
        if (context.mounted) {
          Utils.showSnackbarFunction(context, SnackBarType.error, error.toString());
        }
        print(stackTrace);
        changeLoginStatus();
      });
    }
```

However instead of Logging in I am getting an error in the snackbar:

```
 Here in error section type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
```

I am not able to remove this.
This is the function

```
 Future<dynamic> loginApi(dynamic data) async {
    try {
      dynamic response = await _service.getPostAPIResponse(AppUrl.logIn, data);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

that in turns calls this api endpoint :

```
@override
  Future getPostAPIResponse(String url, dynamic data) async {
    dynamic responseJson;
    try {
      Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
      print("Here in post api ${data.runtimeType}");
      print(url);

      dynamic response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse(url), body: data, headers: headers)
          .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 16));
      responseJson = returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      print("Error");
      throw FetchDataException(message: 'No Internet Exception');
    }
    return responseJson;
  }
```

This is the return response function

```
dynamic returnResponse(dynamic response) {
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
      case 201:
        dynamic jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        return jsonResponse;
      case 400:
        throw BadRequestException(
            message: jsonDecode(response.body.toString()));
      case 404:
        throw PageNotFoundException(message: response.body.toString());
      default:
        throw FetchDataException(
            message:
                'Error occured while fetching data from server. Code ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

The error that I am receiving is a bad Request error with code 400
Can anybody point out as to where am i wrong?